# Issue with Batch file printing "=" when I don't want it to

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting

I obviously am not a windows batch scripting guy so apologies for my extreme ignorance on this.

With that I'm starting with a file that has information listed out as follows:

```
[xxxxx yyyyy]
attribute1= value
attribute2 = value
[xxxxx yyyyy]
attribute1= value
attribute2 = value
```

What I'd like is to just print out "yyyyy", essentially the second field within the brackets

I'm using the following loop:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=[] " %I in ('type file') do @echo %I
```

this then prints out:

```
yyyyy
=
=
yyyyy
=
=
```

I would like to ignore all lines which do not have this bracketed information.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `type file ^|findstr /R /C:"\[.*\]"`

Comment: Two more solutions: `for /F "usebackq tokens=2 delims= " %%I in ("file") do for /F delims^=]^ eol^= %%J in ("%%I") do if not "%%~I" == "%%J" echo %%J` which does not start in background one more command compress for processing the lines in `file`. `for /F "tokens=2 delims=[] " %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /R /X /C:"\[..* ..*\]" "file"') do echo %%I` is very restrictive as there is run in a background command process `findstr` to search for lines starting with `[` and 1 or more characters and ending with 1 or more characters and `]` containing a space inside.

Comment: for /f "tokens=2 delims=[] " %I in ('type file ^|findstr /b "[" ^|findstr /e "]" ') do @echo %I

Comment: You guys are all great, thanks so much for the help, very much appreciated!